# Comparing floating vs int numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays: one of the them is obtained using sinusoidal functions (and so, it has float values), while the other array consists of integers. An example of such an array is:

```
x = np.array([0.43, 2.11, 3.67, 4.12, 7.05, 8.87, 9.1, 11, 11.67])
y = np.array([1, 3, 5, 9, 10])
```

The two arrays are much larger than this toy example. But x is larger than y and contains elements of y within it. The problem is that naively you have to check for a given element within y in x two times: once by rounding up and another by rounding down. So a simple np.round() will not suffice.

```
np.floor(x)
# array([0., 3., 4., 8., 9.])

np.ceil(x)
# array([ 1.,  4.,  5.,  9., 10.])
```

For example, for floor(x), 0 doesn't exist in y, but ceil(x) gives 1 and that is present in y. So, for each element in x, it would need to be rounded up and down and then compared to each element in y to find a match.

Is there an efficient and/or better way to achieve this?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing to both floor/ceil seems reasonable.

```
out = x[np.isin(np.floor(x), y) | np.isin(np.ceil(x), y)]
```

Output: `array([0.43, 2.11, 3.67, 4.12, 8.87, 9.1 ])`

If you have enough memory to broadcast, you could check if the absolute distance with any value of `y` is within 1:

```
out = x[(abs(x-y[:, None]) < 1).any(axis=0)]
# array([0.43, 2.11, 3.67, 4.12, 8.87, 9.1 ])

# or to get values of y
out = y[(abs(x-y[:, None]) < 1).any(axis=1)]
# array([ 1,  3,  5,  9, 10])
```

Comment: I get the error: ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1754,) (2040,)``` since my ```x``` and ```y``` are of different lengths?

Comment: My code doesn't require the arrays to have the same shape, please double check what you did and provide a reproducible example that triggers this error.